# Does Promise.all() run in sequential or parallel?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

**Does Promise.all() run in sequential or parallel in Javascript?**

For Example:

```js
    const promises = [promise1(), promise2(), promise3()]
    Promise.all(promises)
    .then(data => {
        // whatever 
    });
```

Does `promise1()` execute and resolve before moving onto promise2() or does `promise1()`, `promise2()`, and `promise 3()` all run in parallel at the same time? I would assume like Node, Javascript in the browser to be single threaded thus they don't run in parallel?

Comment: No, they are asynchronous.  Single threaded does not mean they run synchronously or in parallel.  A single thread can still time share.

Comment: Node is **single threaded in user code**. If you call two promises that read files, they can be read in the **same time**. Continuations (results) are again single threaded.

Comment: Angular does not (or should not) affect the Promise runtime semantics

Comment: @Thankyou, that's true but I find it hard to trust zone.js. Angular relies on several additions to native Promises provided by zone.js. Try writing an `async` function with `--target ES2017` or higher and see change detection fail miserably.

Comment: Neither! `Promise.all()` doesn't run anything. It aggregates Promises, where each Promise is an abstraction of a value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are Promises implemented in Javascript without threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082867/how-are-promises-implemented-in-javascript-without-threads)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Javascript is a single threaded application. However, asynchronous calls allow you to not be blocked by that call. This is particularly useful when making REST API calls. For example your `promise1()` can make a REST API call and before it waits for the results, another REST API call can be made from `promise2()`. This pseudo-parallelism is thus achieved by not waiting on API servers to do the tasks and fire multiple such calls to either same or different API endpoints in parallel. This allows your code to continue executing that parts that are not dependent on resolution of the promises.

So yes, `promise1()`, `promise2()` and `promise3()` can be said to be running in parallel in that respect. And there is a chance that `promise2()` gets resolved before `promise1()` and so on. The function `Promise.all()` waits for all the promises provided to it to fulfill or at least one of them to fail.

Learn more about Javascript event loops in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0) by Jake Archibald.

Answer (score 9):

`Promise.all` does not make your promises run in parallel.
`Promise.all` does not make your promises run at all.
What `Promise.all` does, is just waiting for all the promises to complete.

The line of code that actually executes things is this one:

```js
const promises = [promise1(), promise2(), promise3()]
```

Assuming that your promises make HTTP calls:

`promise1()` is executed -> 1 HTTP call going on
`promise2()` is executed -> 2 HTTP calls going on
`promise3()` is executed -> 3 HTTP calls going on

then after a while, in undetermined order, these promises complete.

These 3 HTTP calls could complete in the same time, but in your code, you will have 3 sequential completition. For this reason, you can use `Promise.all` to assure that your callback is executed only when all of your promises complete.

Remember that there's a limit on the amount of parallel HTTP connections you can have inyour environment, look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/985704/7327715